# Is there any way to detected the application setting changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

Is there any way to detected the application setting changes?
please help me if there is a good way to detect the settings changes before saving it, i want to get all settings changes and notify the user that there are changes not saved. i did that manually but i want to know if there is a good way. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by setting? For exemple if the user changes the window size and you want to restore it when the application is launched the next time?

Comment: @Didier No i meant the Settings class that .Net Provided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`SettingChanging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.settingchanging.aspx) event if you need to know before the change happens:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SettingChanging += SettingChanging;

void SettingChanging(object sender, System.Configuration.SettingChangingEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

You can also get the new value by inspecting `e.NewValue`.

Otherwise use `PropertyChanged`:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyChanged += SettingChanged;

void SettingChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```